# Remove "replay", "like", "share" at the end of an embedded YouTube video

Tags: youtube, video

I am trying to loop an embedded YouTube video. I added the `autoplay=1` and the `loop=1` parameters, but it doesn't loop.

Can I remove "replay", "like", "share" at the end of an embedded YouTube video?

Seems that prevents the looping.

Comment: There are currently no parameters offered by their API that support this http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. If you really don't like it, consider using a different service, such as [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This stops the show of the junk atop (you need to change the file #):

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/D8EicB4v7uM?showinfo=0&controls=0&rel=0&amp"
```

You can add `&autoplay=1` but it is not very viewer friendly.